# Expand/Collapse First Field Value in PivotTable using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, expand

I am trying to get a code to only expand the first value of the row fields, no matter what it is.

```
Public Sub PivotTable_Collapse()

    Dim pT As PivotTable
    Dim pF As PivotField
    Dim rw As Range

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange
    Set rw = .Rows(3)
    
    Set pT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
   
    With pT
        For Each pF In pT.RowFields
            pF.DrillTo pF.rw 'I think this is where I need help
            
            MsgBox rw
        Next pF
    End With
    End With
```

[image]

This worked for me! Here is the resolution below.

```
Sub ExpandFirstSchool()
'
   Dim rw As Range
     With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange
        Set rw = .Rows(3)
     End With
     rw.Cells(rw.Cells.Count).Select

     rw.Cells(rw.Cells.Count).ShowDetail = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (assuming I understood what you want to do)

```vb
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
      
With pt.PivotFields("Col001").PivotItems(1)
    'you can use one of these....
    .ShowDetail = True 'expand one level down
    .DrillTo "Col002"  'expand one level using field name
    .DrillTo "Col003"  'expand two levels using field name
End With
```

My test data row fields are named "Col001", "Col002", "Col003"